# Show which photos are not backed up to Google yet

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, backup, 7.0-nougat, google-photos

I was using Google Photos in my Samsung J7 + Android 6, and it overlaid a small symbol on each photo which was in my phone and not synced to G Photos yet (I had disabled auto backup, so I did it manually).

I switched phones to Samsung J7 Prime + Android 7, and now I cannot see that small symbol anymore.
So I do not know which photos are synced and which are not.

**Can that be done under Android 7?**

Comment: I don't think It's an Android 7 problem. The app was updated maybe a year ago and it simply stopped showing the symbol. Are you sure that the app on the older phone is up to date?

Comment: @SSS - You seem to be right. I had reset my old phone, but still with Marshmallow. Now it doesn't show the symbol anymore either, so I guess it has a new version of the app as well.